# Why JSP doesn't get Struts 2 action fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have a little problem with printing field in a jsp page. I've managed persistency with hibernate.

When I go to jsp page, it displays nothing. How can I modify jsp in order to print fields of `prodotti` of a scontrino?

**Action Class**

```
public class ScontrinoStruts extends ActionSupport implements UserAware{
        
        private static java.lang.Float iva = 22.00f;
        
        private String valori;
    
        private int idScontrino;
        private Date data;
        private java.lang.Float importoTotale;
        private int totalePezzi;
        
        private int ID_Anagrafica;//idanagrafica
        private Anagrafica anagrafica;
        private AnagraficaDAO anagraficaDAO = AnagraficaDAOFactory.getDAO();
        
        private int idProdotto;
        private List<Prodotto> prodotti = new ArrayList<Prodotto>();
        private Prodotto prodotto;
    
        private Scontrino scontrino = new Scontrino();
        List<Scontrino> scontrini = new ArrayList<Scontrino>();
        ScontrinoDAO scontrinoDAO = ScontrinoDAOFactory.getDAO();
        ProdottoDAO prodottoDAO = ProdottoDAOFactory.getDAO();
        
        public String showScontrino(){
            scontrino = scontrinoDAO.getScontrino(idScontrino);
            return "success";
        }
        //getters and setters
    }
```

**`struts.xml`**

```
    <action name="showScontrino" method="showScontrino"
        class="it.unirc.pjam.Action.ScontrinoStruts">
        <result name="success">/scontrino.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

**JSP**

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>Descrizione</td>
            <td>prezzo</td>
        </tr>
        <s:iterator value="scontrino.prodotti">
            <tr>
                <td><s:property value="idProdotto" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="descrizione" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="prezzo" /></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </table>
```

Comment: Do you have getter for `prodotti` in `scontrino`? Are you sure that `scontrino` isn't null?

Comment: @AleksandrM yes!

Comment: @AleksandrM  

public Set<Prodotto> getProdotti() {
  return prodotti;
 }

 public void setProdotti(Set<Prodotto> prodotti) {
  this.prodotti = prodotti;
 }
 
 public void addProdotto(Prodotto prodotto){
  this.prodotti.add(prodotto);
 }

Comment: What is the URL did you use to call the action? What is the package declaration in `struts.xml`?

Comment: @RomanC this is: /progettoFinale/secure/showScontrino.action?idScontrino=3

Comment: @AleksandrM i'm sure that "scontrino" is not null: http://oi66.tinypic.com/2n0rgi8.jpg

Comment: @RomanC package declaration is right: `<package name="it.unirc.pjam.Action" namespace="/secure" extends="struts-default">`

Comment: What is the parameter value when you call dao method? What size of the collection `prodotti` returned by this method? Did you write ever testcases to test your actions?

Comment: @RomanC I don't understand first question - second question: [link](http://oi63.tinypic.com/301oyn7.jpg) - third question, no, I never used testcases.

Comment: Can you show the code for `Scontrino` class?

Comment: @RomanC [this is `Scontrino`](https://pastebin.com/NVTYzZwQ)

Comment: Can you show the code for class `Prodotto`?

Comment: @RomanC [this is `Prodotto`](https://pastebin.com/kEq32b3x)

Comment: What is the tld definition for `s:` prefix? Do you have ognl library on the classpath, what is the version, what is the version of Struts? Can you show a list of libraries in the WEB-INF/lib of deployed/packaged war

Comment: @RomanC I use this in other working jsps: `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>`

Comment: @RomanC i think that this is not the problem. I have other pages working with this tld definition.

Comment: Refresh the page you might not see other questions in the comment

Comment: @RomanC [version](http://oi65.tinypic.com/50jleq.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure you have `getScontrino()` method in the action class?

Comment: @RomanC thank you, you have resolved my problem!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Congratulations! We've won a hangman game. If you need to know why, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44707100/573032) answer. Unfortunately nobody cares about this problem.

Comment: @RomanC thank you for your help. Can you advice to me how can I show `Scontrino` fileds as JSON? I know there is JSON Plugin but i don't know how I can configure it and action.

Comment: This is different question, I could answer it if you ask it in a separate question.

Comment: @RomanC I opened another question. Check if you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields a displayed via OGNL expression that is used to traverse the object properties to find the value. Attributes such as `value` is used to parse for OGNL expression first before returning its value. How OGNL expression is evaluated you can find in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20856600/573032) answer.

You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24640995/573032) answer to understand what is the action context that is used by OGNL when it's searching the values.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22872041/573032) answer will guide you how to provide getter for the list that is iterated.

Take a deep learning into OGNL language guide with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22970293/573032) answer.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20425283/573032) answer will teach you how to use dot notation to access beans' properties.